# When compiling an assembly language file from the command line on Snow Leopard, which compiler should be used?

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, assembly

I am writing some programs in 100% assembly language and compiling them from the shell in Mac OS X 10.6.7 Snow Leopard.

I am a little confused as to which compiler should be used.  Apple documentation refers to as, but Snow Leopard ships with NASM.  Finally, I am under the impression (could be wrong), that GNU Assembler (GAS), can preform this function as well.

Which is the preferred assembler ?

Thanks,

Scott

Answer (score 0):

i found a similar question that was posted earlier.  See if this applies:
[gas vs. nasm: which assembler produces the best code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1282628/gas-vs-nasm-which-assembler-produces-the-best-code)

I have also found you two articles for GAS vs. NASM: 
[1] http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-unix-assembly-gas-nasm-programming.html
[2] http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-gas-nasm/index.html

Comment: Thanks for the links Gary.  My main concern is not which is "better" or which produces more optimized code or even syntax (although I prefer NASM to GAS when it comes to syntax), rather, which is preferred amongst Mac developers ?  I want to make sure I follow the crowd in this case.

Comment: Iv been working with Mac for a period of time, @ times, when i deal with assembly, i'd go for NASM, simply because i learnt mine through that channel.  but as far as i know, to my limited understanding, performance-wise, they are much the same in my usage, plus it looks to me that they are not difficult to be converted into one another through a script(could be available on the net, but i haven't made any attempt to locate that before).